# Trying to use ES2015 Module system for libraries that are not installed via npm

Tags: ecmascript-6

So I have a couple of dependency libraries for a custom web sdk that I am trying to get up and running.

The libraries are in a root folder I called `modules/` and this is how I included them inside the HTML file:

```
<script type="module" src="modules/xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6.js"></script>
```

and this is how I am importing it into the `index.js` file:

```
import { XmSdk } from './modules/xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6';
```

For which I get the error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

I thought adding `type="module"` to the `<script>` tags would be sufficient to solve this problem, but quite frankly I have never used ES2015 Module system without `node_modules/` installed.

Below is the `index.html` file where I am loading the `index.js` file in a script tag below:

```
<html>
    <head>
       
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modules/xm/css/xmui.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
            <!-- SDK's CORE API module -->
            <!-- <script type="module" src="modules/xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6.js"></script> -->
            <!-- SDK's Default UI Handler module  -->
            <!-- <script type="module" src="modules/xm/js-es6/xmui-es6.js"></script>  -->
            <script src="js/ext/require.js"></script>
            <script>
                requirejs.config({
                    baseUrl: '',
                    paths: {
                        XmSdk: '/xmwl/xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6',
                        XmUIHandler: '/xmwl/xm/js-es6/xmui-es6'
                    }
                });
            </script>
        
        <!-- SDK's CORE API module -->
        <!-- <script type="module" src="modules/xm/js/xmsdk.js"></script> -->
        <!-- SDK's Default UI Handler module  -->
        <!-- <script type="module" src="modules/xm/js/xmui.js"></script>   -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input id="username" type="text"/><br>
        <!-- <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" type="text"/><br> -->
        <button id="loginButton" type="button">Login</button> 
        <button id="logoutButton" type="button">Logout</button>
        <br>
        <div class="transmitContainer"></div>
    </div>
    
    <form id="resumeAuthForm" style="display:none" method="post" action="logout.html">
        <input type="hidden" id="resumeAuthFormToken" name="xm_auth_token"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="resumeAuthFormUsername" name="user_name"/>
    </form>
        <!-- <script>
            require(['XmSdk', 'XmUIHandler'], (xmsdk, xmui) => {
 
            });
        </script> -->
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with npm. It sounds more likely that you have never used modules *in the browser* before?

Comment: Please show us how you are loading the `index.js` file. That appears to be the culprit, it's the one that is not considered to be a module by your browser.

Comment: @Bergi, I added the `index.html` file above, where I am loading the `index.js` file in a `<script>` tag and now that I am looking at it, I think I need to add a `type="modules"` to that.

Comment: Yes, exactly :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only load the **entry** point to your program using a `<script>` element. Use `type="module"` to mark it as an ES6 module (only modules can import other modules):

```
<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
```

**Don't** load additional modules using `<script>` elements.

`<script type="module" src="modules/xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6.js"></script>` is **replaced by** `import { XmSdk } from './modules/xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6';`